# OleDbConnection SQL Server Database in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledbconnection

Can I create OleDbConnection object in c# using SQL Server connection string? if yes what provider do I need to use? Any sample code will help if possible.

Comment: You can, but why would you want to do that? Just use the classes already provided by the framework in System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: I have a reason. When using script tasks in SSIS. The standard connection is OLEDB and using the connection string used in the control/dataflow often provided from parameter or parent package.

Comment: [You might want to check out this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to parse the parameters of the SqlConnectionStringBuilder into a  [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = 
new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Provider"] = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
builder["Data Source"] = "C:\\Sample.mdb";
builder["User Id"] = "Admin;NewValue=Bad";

var connectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

And create the [connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
public void InsertRow(string connectionString, string insertSQL)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // The insertSQL string contains a SQL statement that
        // inserts a new row in the source table.
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(insertSQL);

        // Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
        command.Connection = connection;

        // Open the connection and execute the insert command.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the
        // code exits the using block.
    }
}
```

*Sources from Microsoft documentation*